# how to close multiple dialog and bottomsheet dialog fragment in single activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design

I have 8 dialogues and 2 bottom sheet fragments in a single activity. then how can I close in ondestroy() if any dialogue is opened? is it a good way to make a global object of dialogue in activity and check in onDestroy() method? if it's open then close. If any other efficient way please inform me.

Now i dismiss in onDestroy() method but i think it's not good way to make global object of all dialog and botomsheet fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you create the dialog you can apply it to a variable e.g.

```
val someDialog: SomeDialog? = null

override fun onResume() {
    someDialog = SomeDialog().show(parentFragmentManager)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    someDialog?.dismiss()
    someDialog = null
}
```

if you create several, then you can add to an arraylist and loop through to dismiss and remove

```
val someDialogs: ArrayList<SomeDialog> = arrayListOf()

override fun onResume() {
    someDialogs.add(SomeDialog().show(parentFragmentManager))
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    someDialogs.forEach {
        it.dismiss()
    }
}
```

The same can be applied for bottomSheetDialogs and its perfectly acceptable to do so like this